# Consult database that lives on computer from app script

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cloud

I'm trying to do a program that when someone writes data in the first row of a google sheet, the program pre-populates the following ones with the data returned by a query to an SQL database based on what the user wrote (in real time). I know it sounds strange but it's not for my own use.

I've decided to do it with apps script (using the onEdit function). However, the SQL database lives on the computer as it's used by other programs which I haven't written and data is added to the database several times a day (in a folder inside the desktop). By reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) I've understood that you can only access the database if it lives on the cloud.

Therefore, I would like to know how I could approach this problem and if it's even possible to implement it.

I hope I've explained it well, if clarification is needed, feel free to ask me. I would be really thankful if someone could help me!

### Edit:

Finally found a solution: I made an API with django that interacts with the database file that lives on the desktop of the computer and then I used [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to make localhost be visible from google servers.

Comment: @Kos Sorry, I'm confused with that question, I'm new to this part of programming (all I've done is python scripts and simple web development). Can I connect to a sql file that lives on the desktop of the computer with that answer?

Comment: You cannot connect, only if you have ip address

Comment: You need to expose your db to the internet. There are tunneling services from localhost like ngrok